# Display weirdness after update, PC unusable

Tags: graphics, gpu, flicker

Please forgive me if this is already covered somewhere, I'm using the Stack exchange app on my phone because my PC is unusable.

Today, I ran the usual updates Ubuntu provides me with, but when I turned the PC back on after shutting down, it started flickering after logging in. Sometimes it was the whole screen, sometimes the sidebar, and after at least a minute, I get kicked out onto the login screen. dmesg shows multiple context resets due to GPU hangs, whatever that means.

I already ran apt update and afterwards apt upgrade, but no luck.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am having the same problem out of nowhere, presumably after the latest update. I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Yes, 20.04.1 LTS. I did some digging, and the thing that's causing the problems is very likely a bug in the i915 graphics driver. I just did a complete, clean reinstall, where it loaded all the updates from the internet, and the problem still persists.

Comment: I'm running apt update && upgrade right now, let's see where this goes.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Worked fine before, and I've been using 20.04 LTS since 2020. nVidia GeForce GTX on AMD Ryzen.

Comment: @pram While I wasn't able to find a cause, I did find a workaround: In the boot parameters in grub (where it normally says something like `quiet splash`, put down `quiet splash nomodeset`. This will default to a graphics driver or sth, which will definitely degrade your performance, but it should make it possible to at least log in. In my case, it must've been the driver for the Intel i500 integrated graphics, which doesn't seem applicable here. Maybe try switching graphics drivers. In your case I'd recommend editing the startup options in grub first in case something breaks.